# Start an action after timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

In my iOS app I've to do an action after a delay. I will explain it better: my app can recognize some audio frequency:

- 18100 Hz
- 18200 Hz
- 18300 Hz
- 18500 Hz

To do that I've modified the [pitch detector](https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector). I want to start a timer when the device doesn't recognize one of the frequency that I've setter up in my app.
I made so:

```
- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    watermarkReceived = YES;
    
    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18000 && frequencyRecived <= 18110 && !water1) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"1"];
            water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water1 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18115 && frequencyRecived <= 18250 && !water2) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"2"];
            water1 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water2 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18255 && frequencyRecived <= 18440 && !water3) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"3"];
            water1 = water2 = water4 = NO;
            water3 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18450 && !water4) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"4"];
            water1 = water2 = water3 = NO;
            water4 = YES;
        }
    } else {
        
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"Nessuna postazione"];
        water1 = water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
    }
}
```

In the `else` section I've to start a timer that it count for 10 seconds, after this time I've to write a label. I tried to use the following solution:

`[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> inModes:<#(NSArray *)#>]`

, but it never call the selector method because every time the app execute the code in `else` it restart the timer.
Can you suggest me a solution to solve this issue?
Thanks

### UPDATE

I follow the answer, but it doesn't work. I post here the code updated:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    BOOL watermarkReceived;
    float frequencyRecived;
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    BOOL water1, water2, water3, water4;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSTimer *timer;

@end

- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    watermarkReceived = YES;
    
    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {
        
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18000 && frequencyRecived <= 18110 && !water1) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"1"];
            water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water1 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18115 && frequencyRecived <= 18250 && !water2) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"2"];
            water1 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water2 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18255 && frequencyRecived <= 18440 && !water3) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"3"];
            water1 = water2 = water4 = NO;
            water3 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18450 && !water4) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"4"];
            water1 = water2 = water3 = NO;
            water4 = YES;
        }
    } else {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(noPosition) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
//        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"Nessuna postazione"];
        water1 = water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
    }
}

- (void)noPosition {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"Nessuna postazione"];
}
```

PS: I understood the other problems you told me and I will solve in the future, for now I need to fix the timer issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `NSTimer`. In the `else` branch, check if the timer already exists and, if not, create and schedule it. In the main branch of the `if`, invalidate and destroy the timer.

Also, your `if` statement has a number of holes and is overly complex. You have already checked that the frequency is > 18000 so you don't need to check it again. You are also using `if, else if` to simplify because each is a distinct range, and if one range is detected then none of the other ranges can be. In this way you can just check that the upper range bound is not exceeded in the inner `if`.

Also, setting the text in the background looks wrong. UI updates need to be made from the main thread

---

Something like:

```
- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    watermarkReceived = YES;

    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {

        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;

        if (frequencyRecived <= 18110) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"1"];
            water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water1 = YES;
        }
        else if (frequencyRecived <= 18250) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"2"];
            water1 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water2 = YES;
        }
        else if (frequencyRecived <= 18440) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"3"];
            water1 = water2 = water4 = NO;
            water3 = YES;
        }
        else {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"4"];
            water1 = water2 = water3 = NO;
            water4 = YES;
        }
    } else {
        if (self.timer == nil) {
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:... target:self selector:... userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }

        water1 = water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code, but the app is not calling the selector method. I update my question with the new code. I hope you can help me to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: I missed a check in my code. And why are you doing things in the background? You may not see any updates when updating UI from the background. Stop doing that...

Comment: I did that, but still not working. I update the UI in background otherwise I can't update it without stopping the listener and I can't stop it. If I update the UI in the main thread, I've to stop the listener otherwise the phone crash. I saw that it doesn't call the selector method... I don't know why...

Comment: Your understanding of background is wrong. If it crashes you have some other problem. You must stop updating the UI in the background.